# Starting Location Services In Background IN iOS7 or later at any point in time

Tags: ios, objective-c, location, ios7, cllocationmanager

My algorithm wishes to work this way :
If the state of my server changes I send a remote notification to my application (whose state will be probably suspended or not-running).  But, before notifying the user I wish to run some code . It wasn't possible before iOS 7 but, it's possible in iOS 7 and later. [(Visit this for further details)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19347150/can-i-use-apple-push-notification-service-to-have-my-app-do-something-without-no)

The code I wish to run includes tracking the location of user once and then stop. But, the background mode for tracking location requires to start updating location in foreground and as app moves to background the `CLLocationManager Delegate` automatically gets location updates. 
But, I just wish to track once at some point in time and then stop it.

PS: The state of my server can change at any time. So, I can't use any timers or intervals

Comment: @Wain I hope that you can help me with this

Answer (score 0):

**I found the problem/solution.** When it is time to start location service and stop background task, background task should be stopped with a delay (I set 1 second). Otherwise location service wont start.

Another important notice, max background time in iOS 7 is now 3 minutes instead of 10 minutes.

Maybe it will help someone.

EDITED:

After writing a small example, I found out that the Location Service should be also left ON for a couple of seconds (in my example it is 3 seconds). In ".plist" file set UIBackgroundModes to "location". Example:

**ScheduledLocationManager.h**

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <CoreLocation/CoreLocation.h>

@interface ScheduledLocationManager : NSObject <CLLocationManagerDelegate>

-(void)getUserLocationWithInterval:(int ) interval ;

@end
```

**ScheduledLocationManager.m**

```
#import "ScheduledLocationManager.h"

int const kMaxBGTime = 170; //3 min - 10 seconds (as bg task is killed faster)
int const kTimeToGetLocations = 3;

@implementation ScheduledLocationManager{
    UIBackgroundTaskIdentifier bgTask;
    CLLocationManager *locationManager;
    NSTimer *checkLocationTimer;
    int checkLocationInterval;
    NSTimer *waitForLocationUpdatesTimer;
}

- (id)init
{
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        locationManager = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
        locationManager.delegate = self;
        locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest;
        locationManager.distanceFilter = kCLDistanceFilterNone;

        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidEnterBackground:) name:UIApplicationDidEnterBackgroundNotification object:nil];
        [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(applicationDidBecomeActive:) name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification object:nil];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)getUserLocationWithInterval:(int ) interval
{
    checkLocationInterval = (interval > kMaxBGTime)? kMaxBGTime : interval;
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];
}

- (void)timerEvent:(NSTimer*)theTimer
{
    [self stopCheckLocationTimer];
    [locationManager startUpdatingLocation];

    // in iOS 7 we need to stop background task with delay, otherwise location service won't start
    [self performSelector:@selector(stopBackgroundTask) withObject:nil afterDelay:1];
}

-(void)startCheckLocationTimer
{
    [self stopCheckLocationTimer];
    checkLocationTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:checkLocationInterval target:self selector:@selector(timerEvent:) userInfo:NULL repeats:NO];
}

-(void)stopCheckLocationTimer
{
    if(checkLocationTimer){
        [checkLocationTimer invalidate];
        checkLocationTimer=nil;
    }
}

-(void)startBackgroundTask
{
    [self stopBackgroundTask];
    bgTask = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] beginBackgroundTaskWithExpirationHandler:^{
        //in case bg task is killed faster than expected, try to start Location Service
        [self timerEvent:checkLocationTimer];
    }];
}

-(void)stopBackgroundTask
{
    if(bgTask!=UIBackgroundTaskInvalid){
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication] endBackgroundTask:bgTask];
        bgTask = UIBackgroundTaskInvalid;
    }
}

-(void)stopWaitForLocationUpdatesTimer
{
    if(waitForLocationUpdatesTimer){
        [waitForLocationUpdatesTimer invalidate];
        waitForLocationUpdatesTimer =nil;
    }
}

-(void)startWaitForLocationUpdatesTimer
{
    [self stopWaitForLocationUpdatesTimer];
    waitForLocationUpdatesTimer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:kTimeToGetLocations target:self selector:@selector(waitForLoactions:) userInfo:NULL repeats:NO];
}

- (void)waitForLoactions:(NSTimer*)theTimer
{
    [self stopWaitForLocationUpdatesTimer];

    if(([[UIApplication sharedApplication ]applicationState]==UIApplicationStateBackground ||
        [[UIApplication sharedApplication ]applicationState]==UIApplicationStateInactive) &&
       bgTask==UIBackgroundTaskInvalid){
        [self startBackgroundTask];
    }

    [self startCheckLocationTimer];
    [locationManager stopUpdatingLocation];
}

#pragma mark - CLLocationManagerDelegate methods

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didUpdateLocations:(NSArray *)locations
{    
    if(checkLocationTimer){
        //sometimes it happens that location manager does not stop even after stopUpdationLocations
        return;
    }

    //TODO: save locations

    if(waitForLocationUpdatesTimer==nil){
         [self startWaitForLocationUpdatesTimer];
    }
}

- (void)locationManager:(CLLocationManager *)manager didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    //TODO: handle error
}

#pragma mark - UIAplicatin notifications

- (void)applicationDidEnterBackground:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    if([self isLocationServiceAvailable]==YES){
        [self startBackgroundTask];
    }
}

- (void)applicationDidBecomeActive:(NSNotification *) notification
{
    [self stopBackgroundTask];
    if([self isLocationServiceAvailable]==NO){
        //TODO: handle error
    }
}

#pragma mark - Helpers

-(BOOL)isLocationServiceAvailable
{
    if([CLLocationManager locationServicesEnabled]==NO ||
       [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]==kCLAuthorizationStatusDenied ||
       [CLLocationManager authorizationStatus]==kCLAuthorizationStatusRestricted){
        return NO;
    }else{
        return YES;
    }
}


@end
```

You have to create instance of ScheduledLocationManager and call getUserLocationWithInterval passing an interval in seconds.

Comment: I am currently reviewing it. I will let you know if it works for me.

Comment: @aMother how it goes for you?

Comment: @Guerrix I was busy and wasn't able to test that. I will let you know if it works.

Comment: @Vizllx will the above example run in the background for a week?