# Doesn't get Push Notification with APNS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, apple-push-notifications

I have followed this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1

As notification has been sent successfully from the server as described in tutorial. But i am not getting it in my device.

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"UUID"])
    {
        if (SYSTEM_VERSION_LESS_THAN(@"6.0"))
        {
            deviceID = [self GetUUID];
        }
        else
        {
            NSUUID* udid= [UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor;
            deviceID = [udid UUIDString];
        }
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setValue:deviceID forKey:@"UUID"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }
    else
    {
        deviceID = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] valueForKey:@"UUID"];
    }

    return YES; }

- (NSString *)GetUUID {
        CFUUIDRef theUUID = CFUUIDCreate(NULL);
        CFStringRef string = CFUUIDCreateString(NULL, theUUID);
        CFRelease(theUUID);
        return (__bridge NSString *)string; }
```

Comment: UUID has nothing to do with delivering APNS - and your code does not show how you get your APNS token and if you send it to server and store it there somehow. David Wong's answer might point you to the right direction. Also check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/q/19031862/653513) It is not exactly the same problem as yours but might offer some clarifications.

Comment: One tesed implementation of `didReceiveRemoteNotification:` can be found [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/19348360/653513)

Comment: One more thing: if you have just created the APNS certificate(s) today you might simply need to wait for a couple of hours.

Answer (score 1):

Have you implemented `application:didReceiveRemoteNotification:` in your application delegate? When you're in app notifications get received there.

Or is it no notification gets sent to you?

Comment: Yeah i have the didReceiveRemoteNotification:

Answer (score 1):

For push notifications you have to register with the push notification token. iOS returns the push notification token with spaces, you have to remove them:

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken 
{

NSString *token = [[devToken description] stringByTrimmingCharactersInSet:      [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"<>"]];
token = [token stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
NSLog(@"token: %@", token);
}
```

Comment: Yes i have done exactly according to the tutorial. Where they placed device token in .php file. And the problem is in receiving notification in device.

Comment: Did you created the appropriate certificated and profiles in Apple Dev Portal?

Comment: Yes, when i install the app first time it has asked me for enabling push notification service.

Comment: That does not mean that the certificates are correct, it means just that you have added the push notification code in your app delegate.

Answer (score 0):

What's the size of your payload? The maximum length is 256bytes. If your payload is over that limit, it may say the push has been sent successfully yet Apple rejects it silently.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Chapters/ApplePushService.html